# Using double quotes within str Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, double-quotes

I am creating the following dataframe and then writing it to a txt file:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['0001'], 'name': ['"LUCA"']})
df.to_csv('names.txt', index=False)
```

I expect my txt file to look like this:

```
key,name
0001,"LUCA"
```

But it is looking like this instead:

```
key,name
0001,"""LUCA"""
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Why do you want the CSV file to look like `0001,"LUCA"` and not `0001,LUCA` ? Do you realise that most programs that read CSV will consider both of those the same?

Comment: Ok but I need it with quotes anyway.

Comment: when I do `df = pd.read_csv("names.csv")`, I get back the correct dataframe with `"LUCA"`. But if there is only a pair of quotes (instead of 3 pairs), they will disappear when I do `df = pd.read_csv("names.csv")`

Comment: as a dataframe it works well, but in the txt file it doesn' t. Don' t know why.

Comment: If I were you, I would create the CSV file by running `import csv; df.to_csv('names.csv', index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)` so that all fields in the CSV file are quoted, that will be a lot less confusing, I think.

Comment: Notice that you are writing a CSV file. Double-quote characters have a special meaning in CSV files. See section 2, items 5 and 7 of the [CSV spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) (which is nowhere near universally followed, but still...)

Comment: To clarify what the other comments are already saying, `to_csv` is correctly escaping the double quotes in your dataframe in the expected format for CSV. If you don't escape them, then most CSV readers (spreadsheet software etc.) will interpret your quotes as enclosing the field and not as part of the field. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `quotechar` in [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to avoid interpreting `"` as the quoting character:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['0001'], 'name': ['"LUCA"']})

df.to_csv('names.txt', index=False, quotechar="'")
```

output file:

```
key,name
0001,"LUCA"
```

This means, however, that if you really need escaping, you will have single quotes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['0001', '0002'], 'name': ['"LUCA"', 'LUCA,']})

df.to_csv('names.txt', index=False, quotechar="'")
```

output:

```
key,name
0001,"LUCA"
0002,'LUCA,'
```